# Adobe air mobile - softKeyboardType is not working when using skinClass to allow scrolling?

Tags: actionscript-3, mobile, air, adobe, flash-builder

I am trying to set the softKeyboardType to email but when ever i use skinClass="spark.skins.mobile.TextAreaSkin" it doesn't change it but when i take off skinClass="spark.skins.mobile.TextAreaSkin" it does work. The problem is i need the skinClass="spark.skins.mobile.TextAreaSkin" class to allow my application so scroll with out it the text does not stay with in the bounds of the text input boxes. Has anyone seen this problem or another fix the the scrolling problem? 

Code examples

```
<s:TextInput softKeyboardType="email" id="id1" width="100%" skinClass="spark.skins.mobile.TextInputSkin" /> 
<s:TextArea softKeyboardType="email" id="id2" height="400" width="100%" skinClass="spark.skins.mobile.TextAreaSkin" />
```

Thank for the help,
Justin

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've checked mobiletheme default.css in flex 4.6 sdk
adobe is using different skins for TextInput and TextArea components

```
TextArea
{
    ...
    skinClass: ClassReference("spark.skins.mobile.StageTextAreaSkin");
}

TextInput
{
    ...
    skinClass: ClassReference("spark.skins.mobile.StageTextInputSkin");
}
```

so I think you should use StageTextAreaSkin or StageTextInputSkin as a skinClass for corresponding components

softKeyboardType will work in this case but text position problem will stay, I think you will need to change/fix StageTextAreaSkin or StageTextInputSkin sources for your scrolling

Answer (score 1):

Confronted with this issue, I came up with a workaround which worked in my case.

Use default skin, set your softKeyboardType.

While doing layout for your screen, create a section which contains the uppermost part of your screen and which you can easily collaps or toggle its includeInLayout property, so when you do that, it will make your TextInput or TextArea to appear over the keyboard, bypassing the scroller for that purpose.

Then, when your field receives focus, in focusIn handler, you collaps or toggle this section. This does two good things: first, it lifts your field over the keyboard, and second, it removes focus from your field (at least in my case it did, not sure 100%, if it doesn't, then shift focus manually). This is good because when you set focus on your field once again (yourfield.setFocus()), the cursor will appear where you want it, within the bounds of your field.

Once done typing, you restore top section to its original state from focusOut or softKeyboardDeactivate handlers.

Hope this helps...

Answer (score 0):

seems like it's flex 4.6 bug

http://forums.adobe.com/message/4122095