# Screen does not pan for soft keyboard in flex mobile app

Tags: apache-flex, air, soft-keyboard

I have created a flex mobile app that uses softKeyboardBehavior "pan" which was working great up until now. I noticed that on Android devices, the soft keyboard pans the screen up just fine in most situations. One view though, I have a List which contains a TextArea in each item renderer. When I edit text in those TextAreas, the soft keyboard does not pan the screen up which hides the text being typed in item renderers on the bottom half of the screen. This lack of panning appears to only happen in lists on Android. It works fine on iOS and Blackberry. If I change the softKeyboardBehavior to "none" this same behavior happens on all devices. Is there anything I can do to make the screen pan when editing text inside Lists?

Comment: have a look here:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9895397/adobe-air-mobile-softkeyboardtype-is-not-working-when-using-skinclass-to-allow

I think it might be helpful for you